# purpose of @doc annotations and generating doc from Rascal Modules

Tags: rascal

I find plenty of @doc annotations through the Rascal Modules, but don't know how they work. I tried to create javadoc but that's not directly supported. I feel that there must be a way to generate a collection of docs by running a process through the modules in a Rascal project. Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Good question which does not have a good answer. The doc tags are used to generate the tutor's pages at http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org, for the standard library and are used by the type checker (to be released) to produce hover help in the IDE. Currently we don't have a process for any project as you described. There should be!

Answer (score 1):

The required information format of `@doc` annotations is documented in the [Tutor documentation](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Tutor/Tutor.html).
This information is used to document, for instance, library functions. To give you an impression: the documentation about the Rascal functions on [Lists](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Libraries/Prelude/List/List.html) is generated from the source code of the List module found [here](https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/blob/master/src/org/rascalmpl/library/List.rsc).

The same information structure is used for complete Tutor pages. For instance, the file [Rascal.concept](https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/blob/master/src/org/rascalmpl/courses/Rascal/Rascal.concept) results in this [Main page](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Rascal.html) of the Rascal tutorial.

There are some cavests:

- The `@doc` tags are not yet used consistently across the code base.
- Hover support for the `@doc` information is still missing in the IDE.